Ubuntu 22.04 freezes during ROS2 "colcon_build --symlink-install"
I am working with ROS2 on Ubuntu 22.04, and when I try to compile my workspace with colcon build --symlink install Ubuntu freezes after a few seconds.
I followed the CPU and RAM usage during the compilation via htop and RAM usage is super high, 14.4 GB/15.3 GB. Is that normal? Without doing anything on desktop it is nearly 2.8 GB/15.3 GB.
Results of htop:


Try increasing the swap to 10 GB or something like that, or buy more RAM. It freezes because all RAM is being used up in the compilation.

Here is the thing: I don't think I need more RAM. My ros2_ws just has 1 package, and that package is from the tutorial. Plus, some turtlebot3 related stuff. So I should not be having that problem.

As you can see yourself, your computer is using almost all of its RAM and that is why it is freezing. If you feel that there is a memory leak and compilation should not take so much RAM, please contact the developer of the application you are compiling. I am sure they have a github issues section where you can report bugs
